# Use API to list the channel names in an MS Teams 'Team' WITH the associated 'incoming-webhooks' url for each one

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I am moving some integrations that use webhooks from Slack to MS Teams.  Slack has a convenient way of overriding the channel name that the message gets posted to in the webhook payload.  MS Teams appears to generate a unique webhook URL per channel.

I'm therefore looking for a way to enumerate the list of channels in a given 'Team' and retrieve the 'incoming-webhook' Connector url for each.

I cannot find a way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the list of channels in Team using [List channels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) API but it is not possible to fetch the Webhook URL's added in each channel.

Answer (score 0):

You should do some API calls to infer that.

First, you should get all teams in your organization. Do to that you should call:

```
GET /groups?$select=id,resourceProvisioningOptions
```

Or:

```
GET /groups?$filter=resourceProvisioningOptions/Any(x:x eq 'Team')
```

You can read more about it at [List all teams in Microsoft Teams for an organization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/teams-list-all-teams). The response will be of the form:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-type: application/json
Content-length: xxx

{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#groups",
    "value": [
        {
            "id": "00e897b1-70ba-4cb9-9126-fd5f95c4bb78",
            "resourceProvisioningOptions": []
        },
        {
            "id": "00f6e045-f884-4359-a617-d459ee626862",
            "resourceProvisioningOptions": [
                "Team"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Then, for each `id` in the response above, you should call to list channels:

```
GET /teams/{id}/channels
```

You can read more about this API at [List Chanels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http). The response will have an entry in its json called `webUrl`. The value of that key, will be the channel URL you are looking for.

Comment: While this is certainly something useful, I don't think it gives the -webhook- information, which is what OP was asking for.

Comment: @TomerShetah Thanks however it’s not the web link to the team I’m after.  It’s the url for the ‘incoming-webhook’ connector so I can work out what the incoming webhook url is for a given channel name.